# How can i convert attribute data to lower case using JavaScript only?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to make auto suggest search. Its working fine only thing i want to improve is that upper and lower case values. I have below `li` list

```
<input type="text" id="filter-search" />

<ul>
    <li filter-value="One Is">One Is (Uppercase)</li>
  <li filter-value="one is">one is (Lowercase)</li>
    <li filter-value="two">Two</li>
    <li filter-value="three">Three</li>
    <li filter-value="four">Four</li>
    <li filter-value="five" >Five</li>
    <li filter-value="six">Six</li>
    <li filter-value="seven">Seven</li>
    <li filter-value="eight">Eight</li>
    <li filter-value="nine">Nine</li>
    <li filter-value="ten" >Ten</li>
</ul>
```

---

```
var inputId     = 'filter-search';
var itemsData   = 'filter-value';
var displaySet = false;
var displayArr = [];

function getDisplayType(element) {
    var elementStyle = element.currentStyle || window.getComputedStyle(element, "");
    return elementStyle.display;
}

document.getElementById(inputId).onkeyup = function() {
    var searchVal = this.value.toLowerCase();
    var filterItems = document.querySelectorAll('[' + itemsData + ']');
    for(var i = 0; i < filterItems.length; i++) {
        if (!displaySet) {
            displayArr.push(getDisplayType(filterItems[i]));
        }
        filterItems[i].style.display = 'none';
        if(filterItems[i].getAttribute('filter-value').toLowerCase().indexOf(searchVal.toLowerCase()) >= 0) {
            filterItems[i].style.display = displayArr[i];       
        }
    }
    displaySet = true;
}
```

The first `li` is not searchable, because it has upper case value, here is [**code**](https://jsfiddle.net/jf5zkuh4/3/) (its few line) Can anyone kindly guide me that how can i fix the issue. I would like to appreciate.

Comment: @brso05 Sure, if you check the provided fiddle you will see all data is searchable by input field but only first `li` is not searchable because it has uppercase value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to do a case-insensitive search, convert both strings to lowercase before comparing:

```
if(filterItems[i].getAttribute('filter-value').toLowerCase().indexOf(searchVal) >= 0) {
```

You could, of course, optimize this by setting the data- attribute value to a lowercase value on the server.

Comment: That's funny. Two answers posted almost at the same time using `toLowerCase()` and `toUpperCase()` :D

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.toUpperCase()` when comparing:

```
if(filterItems[i].getAttribute('filter-value').toUpperCase().indexOf(searchVal.toUpperCase()) >= 0) {
```

https://jsfiddle.net/jf5zkuh4/4/

Comment: Thanks a lot, its working i check it, but @JasonP posted first. I have voted up.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `toLowerCase()` method on any string.

An example of using this:

```
var string = elem.getAttribute('filter-value'); // One Is
string = string.toLowerCase(); // one is
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to make the search case insensitive in order for it to get the first values

```
var inputId     = 'filter-search';
var itemsData   = 'filter-value';
var displaySet = false;
var displayArr = [];

function getDisplayType(element) {
    var elementStyle = element.currentStyle || window.getComputedStyle(element, "");
    return elementStyle.display;
}

document.getElementById(inputId).onkeyup = function() {
    var searchVal = this.value.toLowerCase();
    var filterItems = document.querySelectorAll('[' + itemsData + ']');
    for(var i = 0; i < filterItems.length; i++) {
        if (!displaySet) {
            displayArr.push(getDisplayType(filterItems[i]));
        }
        filterItems[i].style.display = 'none';
        var prop = filterItems[i].getAttribute('filter-value').toLowerCase();
        if(prop.indexOf(searchVal) >= 0) {
            filterItems[i].style.display = displayArr[i];       
        }
    }
    displaySet = true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your if condition as below:

```
if(filterItems[i].getAttribute('filter-value').toLowerCase().indexOf(searchVal) >= 0) {
```